# grouping by column but getting multiple results for each

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate the median `response time` for `conversations` on each date for the last X days.

I use the following query below, but for some reason, it will generate multiple rows with the same date.

```
with grouping as (
        SELECT a.id, d.date, extract(epoch from (first_response_at - started_at)) as response_time
        FROM (
            select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date
            FROM generate_series(0, 2) AS offs
        ) d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN apps a on true
        LEFT OUTER JOIN conversations c ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day'::varchar, c.started_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and a.id = c.app_id 
        and c.app_id = a.id and c.first_response_at > (current_date - (2  || ' days')::interval)::date
      )
      select
      *
      from grouping
      where grouping.id = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT?

Comment: This wont solve it because I don't know which one (if any) of the duplicated rows has the correct median response time

Comment: You are doing a `CROSS JOIN` with `apps` by left joining on true. If you want us to investigate more, please attach sqlfiddle, or scripts to generate sample data and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a number of issues with your query, assuming there aren't any parts you haven't shown us:

- You don't need a CTE for this query.
- From table `apps` you only use column `id` whose value is the same as `c.app_id`. You can remove the table `apps` and select `c.app_id` for the same result.
- When you use `to_char()` you do not first have to `date_trunc()` to a `date`, the `to_char()` function handles that.
- `generate_series()` also works with `timestamps`. Just enter day values with an interval and cast the end result to `date` before using it.

So, removing all the flotsam we end up with this **which does exactly the same as the query in your question** but now we can at least see what is going on.

```
SELECT c.app_id, to_date(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date, 
       extract(epoch from (first_response_at - started_at)) AS response_time
FROM generate_series(CURRENT_DATE - 2, CURRENT_DATE, interval '1 day') d(date)
LEFT JOIN conversations c ON d.date::date = c.started_at::date
                         AND c.app_id = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I'
                         AND c.first_response_at > CURRENT_DATE - 2;
```

You don't calculate the median response time anywhere, so that is a big problem you need to solve. This only requires data from table `conversations` and would look somewhat like this to calculate the median response time for the past 2 days:

```
SELECT app_id, started_at::date AS start_date,
       percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY first_response_at - started_at) AS median_response
FROM conversations
WHERE app_id = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I'
  AND first_response_at > CURRENT_DATE - 2
GROUP BY 2;
```

When we fold the two queries, and put the parameters handily in a single place, this is the final result:

```
SELECT p.id, to_date(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date, 
       extract(epoch from (c.median_response)) AS response_time
FROM (VALUES ('ASnYW1-RgCl0I', 2)) p(id, days)
JOIN generate_series(CURRENT_DATE - p.days, CURRENT_DATE, interval '1 day') d(date) ON true
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT started_at::date AS start_date,
           percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY first_response_at - started_at) AS median_response
    FROM conversations
    WHERE app_id = p.id
      AND first_response_at > CURRENT_DATE - p.days
    GROUP BY 2) c ON d.date::date = c.start_date;
```

If you want to change the id of the app or the number of days to look back, you only have to change the `VALUES` clause accordingly. You can also wrap the whole thing in a SQL function and convert the `VALUES` clause into two parameters.

Comment: This is great, almost perfect. Problem is that if there's no result for a date, the app_id is null and this is a problem when a later attempts to aggregate it into arrays

Comment: Then rather than selecting `c.app_id`, just put in the string 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I', since you are not modifying that in the query anyway. Answer updated.

Comment: I would rather not hardcode the `app_id`, as the idea is to remove it an aggregate the data for all apps

Comment: Now you are moving away from your initial question, which I believe I have adequately answered. You can aggregate on `app_id` by putting it in the select list and then grouping by it in the sub-query and then taking it out of the `VALUES` clause.